# javax.net.ssl.SSLKeyException: [Security:090477]Certificate chain received from intranet.xxx.com

Tags: java, ssl, https, weblogic, keystore

javax.net.ssl.SSLKeyException: [Security:090477]Certificate chain received from intranet.xxx.com - 158.171.160.28 was not trusted causing SSL handshake failure.

I am trying to fetch contents as html page from one intranet website using weblogic. While connecting to the website I am getting javax.net.ssl.SSLKeyException: [Security:090477] exception. Where as with the same peice of code I am able to acheive the required using a main class. Please advice on this.

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] lines = null;

        try {
             // configure the SSLContext with a TrustManager
            SSLContext ctx = null;
            try {
                ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                ctx.init(new KeyManager[0], new TrustManager[] {new DefaultTrustManager()}, new SecureRandom());
            } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            SSLContext.setDefault(ctx);

            String url = "https://www.google.com"

            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

            Elements elements = doc.getElementById("table_UniqueReportID").children();
            for(Element element : elements)
            {
                System.out.println(element.nodeName());
                if(element.nodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("tbody"))
                {
                    Elements rowElements = element.children();
                    for(Element currentRow : rowElements)
                    {
                        System.out.println(currentRow.text());
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private static class DefaultTrustManager implements X509TrustManager {


        @Override
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)
                throws CertificateException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)
                throws CertificateException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to import the certificate into keystore and signers to java cacerts as well.

And make sure certificate common name is same as your serever name.

For example..if you see SBI online banking certificate then it's common name is something like

CN = www.onlinesbi.com

We should have to import the certificate into keystore to work.